# Why is my function not running and getting an invalid memory error?

Tags: c, multithreading, ucontext

I'm trying to simulate threads swapcontext() and whatnot but I have some issues:

1. The callback function doesn't run
2. I get a memory error from free():
   free(): invalid size
   Aborted
3. How do I wait until all the threads are done?

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024

typedef struct thread {
    ucontext_t context;
    void* stack;
    int done;
} thread_t;

thread_t thread1, thread2;

void thread1_function(int argc, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, argc);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Thread 1 count: %d\n", i);
        swapcontext(&thread1.context, &thread2.context);
    }

    thread1.done = 1;
    printf("Thread 1 done\n");

    va_end(args);
}

void thread2_function() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Thread 2 count: %d\n", i);
        swapcontext(&thread2.context, &thread1.context);
    }

    printf("Thread 2 done\n");
    thread2.done = 1;
}

int main() {
    // Allocate stacks for each thread
    thread1.stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    thread2.stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

    // Initialize the execution context for each thread
    getcontext(&thread1.context);
    thread1.context.uc_stack.ss_sp = thread1.stack;
    thread1.context.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
    makecontext(&thread1.context, (void (*)())thread1_function, 1, 2, 0);

    getcontext(&thread2.context);
    thread2.context.uc_stack.ss_sp = thread2.stack;
    thread2.context.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
    makecontext(&thread2.context, (void (*)())thread2_function, 0);

    // Switch to thread1
    swapcontext(&thread1.context, &thread2.context);

    // Free stacks
    free(thread1.stack);
    free(thread2.stack);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code is supposed to run both my callback function instead of I get below error and without the function at all (as far i know):

Thread 2 count: 0
free(): invalid size
Aborted

Comment: What are the values passed to `free()` and received from `malloc()`? Where exactly does the error happen? Run the code in a debugger to create a backtrace. Also, make sure this is actually a [mcve]. Further, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: From [the documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/makecontext.html) of `makecontext`: "The uc_link member should be initialised prior to the call to makecontext()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my tests, `STACK_SIZE` must be set to at least 6 KB, otherwise I get the error message `free(): invalid size` or a segmentation fault. Therefore, I recommend setting `STACK_SIZE` to at least 32 KB in order to be reasonably sure that the stack size is sufficient.

In your posted code, you set up

- `thread1.context` to run the function `thread1_function` and
- `thread2.context` to run the function `thread2_function`.

However, in the line

```
swapcontext(&thread1.context, &thread2.context);
```

of the function `main`, you overwrite `thread1.context` with the current context and execute `thread2.context`. This means that `thread1.context` is no longer set up to execute the function `thread1_function`, but is instead set up to execute the remainder of `main`.

Because you are now executing `thread2.context`, the function `thread2_function` will be executed. This function will first print

```
Thread 2 count: 0
```

and then it will execute this line:

```
swapcontext(&thread2.context, &thread1.context);
```

As previously stated, `thread1.context` is no longer set up to execute the function `thread1_function`, but is instead set up to execute the remainder of `main`. Therefore, after calling `swapcontext`, the program will execute these lines of `main`:

```
// Free stacks
free(thread1.stack);
free(thread2.stack);

return 0;
```

These lines will terminate the program, causing nothing else to be printed.

In order to fix this, you should not store the context of `main` in `thread1.context`. It should be stored in a separate object.

Also, if you don't set the value of `thread1.context.uclink` and `thread2.context.uclink` to a non-zero value, then the program will terminate as soon as `thread1_function` or `thread2_function` returns.

One possible solution is to set the member `uclink` to the context that is executing the function `main`. The function `main` can then be programmed to terminate if both threads are done, otherwise it will set the context to the thread that is not yet done.

Another issue is that the line

```
swapcontext(&thread1.context, &thread2.context);
```

in the function `thread1_function` is not meaningful if thread 2 is already done, because in that case, setting the context to thread 2 will cause thread 2 to repeat its final time slice (with the stack that has already been used by the final time slice of thread 2, which may cause the program to crash).

For this reason, that line should be changed to

```
if ( !thread2.done ) {
    swapcontext(&thread1.context, &thread2.context);
}
```

The function `thread2_function` has the same problem.

Here is a solution which fixes all errors mentioned above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 32768

typedef struct thread {
    ucontext_t context;
    void* stack;
    int done;
} thread_t;

thread_t thread1, thread2;
ucontext_t main_context;

void thread1_function(int argc, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, argc);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Thread 1 count: %d\n", i);
        if ( !thread2.done ) {
            swapcontext(&thread1.context, &thread2.context);
        }
    }

    thread1.done = 1;
    printf("Thread 1 done\n");

    va_end(args);
}

void thread2_function() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Thread 2 count: %d\n", i);
        if ( !thread1.done ) {
            swapcontext(&thread2.context, &thread1.context);
        }
    }

    printf("Thread 2 done\n");
    thread2.done = 1;
}

int main() {
    // Allocate stacks for each thread
    thread1.stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    thread2.stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

    // Initialize the execution context for each thread
    getcontext(&thread1.context);
    thread1.context.uc_stack.ss_sp = thread1.stack;
    thread1.context.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
    thread1.context.uc_link = &main_context;
    makecontext(&thread1.context, (void (*)())thread1_function, 1, 2, 0);

    getcontext(&thread2.context);
    thread2.context.uc_stack.ss_sp = thread2.stack;
    thread2.context.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
    thread2.context.uc_link = &main_context;
    makecontext(&thread2.context, (void (*)())thread2_function, 0);

    // Switch to thread1
    swapcontext( &main_context, &thread1.context );

    // If a thread is still running, set context to that thread
    if ( !thread1.done ) {
        setcontext( &thread1.context );
    }
    if ( !thread2.done ) {
        setcontext( &thread2.context );
    }

    // Free stacks
    free(thread1.stack);
    free(thread2.stack);

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Thread 1 count: 0
Thread 2 count: 0
Thread 1 count: 1
Thread 2 count: 1
Thread 1 count: 2
Thread 2 count: 2
Thread 1 count: 3
Thread 2 count: 3
Thread 1 count: 4
Thread 2 count: 4
Thread 1 count: 5
Thread 2 count: 5
Thread 1 count: 6
Thread 2 count: 6
Thread 1 count: 7
Thread 2 count: 7
Thread 1 count: 8
Thread 2 count: 8
Thread 1 count: 9
Thread 2 count: 9
Thread 1 done
Thread 2 done
```